# Monit not starting after OS upgrade to Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, monit

Iv recently upgraded the version of Ubuntu from 9.04 to 10.04LTS (through 9.10) and now Monit won't start. Doing a `sudo /etc/init.d/monit syntax` says the syntax is ok. If I run the command `sudo /etc/init.d/monit start` I get `Starting daemon monitor: monit`. However if I do a `ps -ef`, then monit is not listed.

If I dig into the `/etc/init.d/monit` file then i can see that the executable that gets run is `/etc/monit/monitrc`. Running this with sudo gives an output of

```
/etc/monit/monitrc: 6: allow: not found
/etc/monit/monitrc: 7: SSL: not found
/etc/monit/monitrc: 8: PEMFILE: not found
/etc/monit/monitrc: 10: check: not found
/etc/monit/monitrc: 11: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

My control file is below:

```
set mailserver localhost
set mail-format { from: me@mydomain.com }
set alert me@mydomain.com

set httpd port 2812 and
allow myuser:mypassword
SSL ENABLE
PEMFILE  /etc/monit/monit.pem

check system my.ip.he.re
    if loadavg (1min) > 4 then alert
    if loadavg (5min) > 2 then alert
    if memory usage > 60% then alert
    if cpu usage (user) > 70% then alert
    if cpu usage (system) > 70% then alert
    if cpu usage (wait) > 70% then alert

include /etc/monit/conf.d/*.monitrc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kyle's post prompted me to look at `/etc/default/monit` and I compared the setup to a newer server.

In older versions of monit you had a line such as `CHECK_INTERVALS=30` in `/etc/default/monit`. This is no longer used and you have to now have a line that looks like `set daemon 30` in your `/etc/monit/monitrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure, but perhaps there is one of those default files for monit that needs to be enabled in `/etc/default` ?

Since the monit file in `/etc/init.d/` is shell script, you can run `sudo bash -x /etc/init.d/monit start` which will trace the script on your screen and might show you where you are going wrong.

Comment: Ehh.. I didn't read your question carefully enough, but I will leave this because it might be the answer for someone else who stumbles upon this from Google.